# can I install multiple versions of php and mysql on xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I am using xampp on windows xp. Recently I felt in need of having more than one version of PHP and mysql.
Is it possible.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this posting on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/123902/getting-xampp-to-work-with-multiple-version-of-php)